# What exactly is the extratrees option in ranger?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

As far as I understand the `splitrule = “extratrees”` option in the package [ranger](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ranger/ranger.pdf) is an implementation of [Geurts et al (2006)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10994-006-6226-1) extremely randomized trees.

In their paper they state:

> At each tree node, this is combined with a **random choice of a certain number of attributes** among which the best one is determined. In the extreme case, the method randomly picks a single attribute and cut-point at each node, and hence builds totally randomized trees whose structures are independent of the target variable values of the learning sample.

1. If I run `ranger` with `splitrule = "extratrees"` but without specifying `mtry` I see in the resulting object that `mtry = 8`. Doesn’t the algorithm also imply a random choice of `mtry` as stated in the article?
2. On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest) there is a small section about extremely randomized trees. In contrast to the paper, it does not mention that the number of features chosen is random but can be specified, which would be in line with what I see in *ranger*. Then I wonder: Could I then still call this extremely randomized trees as implemented in *ranger* according to Geurts et al when writing a paper or is this a "mix" of the default and extremely randomized trees?
3. Wikipedia furthermore says:

   > first, each tree is trained using the whole learning sample (rather than a bootstrap sample)

Nevertheless, I get the out of bag error in the fit object of *ranger*, which in my understanding is impossible if the whole training data is used. Only a cross-validation error would be possible unless in fact bagging is still performed.

So, basically my question is: What exactly is implemented in *ranger* under the option `splitrule = "extratrees"` and why did they deviate from the original paper?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, `extraTrees` does implement Geurts et al. (2006) *[Extremely randomized trees](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10994-006-6226-1)*. The implementation of `extraTrees` has been discussed in detail in Github's thread on that issue so I would strongly urge you read it further [here](https://github.com/imbs-hl/ranger/issues/87).

Regarding the particular questions raised:

1. Yes, but read on! By default the same number of candidates `mtry` is used, this being calculated as the (rounded down) square root of the number variables. It makes sense for `ranger` to use a particular number for `mtry` because that way it can be effectively regularised. Theoretically, we should indeed restrict the choice to a random subset to begin within each tree. Nevertheless as the choice of the attribute to split as well as the split itself are random this difference is mostly a formality.
2. Yes, you can. By far the main novelty in Geurts et al. is the way that nodes are split by choosing cut-points fully at random; that is something that `ranger` definitely does. You could/should specify in the paper that the implementation used is the one from `ranger` to alleviate any uncertainties.
3. You are correct; the default values hurt us here. That said if during training, we sample without replacement (i.e. we set `replace = FALSE`) as well as set the fractions of observation to sample to 1 (i.e. we set `sample.fraction = 1`) we will not get a OOB error and the forest is trained on the whole sample. You might want to create a new issue about this in `ranger`'s github repo. It will mostly be a case of re-adjusting the defaults when `splitrule='extraTrees'` but we can do it manually too.

To recap: If we use `rf <- ranger( ..., splitrule = "extratrees", replace = FALSE, sample.fraction = 1)` we can safely say that we use Geurts et al. implementation. All the core differences between extremely randomized trees and "standard" random forests are respected.

Minor point on regarding reporting OOB or not: While indeed OOB estimates can substitute the presence of a separate test set, I find it much more clear if there is a distinct test set and/or we use repeated CV or bootstrapping. It makes the comparison with other approaches (e.g. a simple linear model or an SVM) more comparable and coherent.

Comment: I think we should add a note to the docs of ranger but don't change the defaults (the other parameters shouldn't change when just selecting another split rule). I created an issue for that: https://github.com/imbs-hl/ranger/issues/408

Comment: @mnwright: You are the boss Marvin. I am just a happy `ranger` user.